# Identity server is keep showing "Showing login: User is not authenticated" in /connect/authorize/callback

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4

Using IdentityServer4, I'm implementing Code flow authorization on an existing system which supports only ResourceOwnerPassword grant type in IdentityServer and works well.

I got into a stage where the user is promoted to authenticate, then redirected to `server connect/authorize/callback`

After that it is not authenticating and coming back to the login page. From the log, I got the following:

1. > Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint for /connect/authorize/callback
2. ValidatedAuthorizeRequest

   ```
   {
   "ClientId": "demo",
   "ClientName": "MVC Client Demo",
   "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
   "AllowedRedirectUris": ["http://openidclientdemo.com:8001/signin-oidc",
   "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"],
   "SubjectId": "anonymous",
   "ResponseType": "code id_token",
   "ResponseMode": "form_post",
   "GrantType": "hybrid",
   "RequestedScopes": "openid profile default-api",
   "State": "CfDJ8DU4Xalc7d9HttaFlZ-UaDhGsjeeEccTfNiNZFz3yYZI9MfXjrXo2TAzT9f6-F2VEdC7bWtcD7HRJgkqrh4t0oTAe_47IBfcm5Fsde9bVRorq-CHcL6_c15Vz1G5LJyEzqX6tyjhcZ2g3J2JjxD1PME1W7sq9YSddhQUJmxt4bVi70wdTtXXp0tH0SKyb0vLCs3eIjOln792nobaFOCM7r3VJ8BfXfpDm2pOOmBlR7zCCBxFCivwj7Zmy5Tu8Z09MvzOaLEkPBSL5i9GyxmGiB0P6osBPYEDyoRfgy2qDigH3QqLmLYjfE6NrgcgIGO9kgXuUT52XgALV_ZKjNbih-Y",
   "Nonce": "636702233595840569.NGQ3NGVlODMtYTVhNy00MjM4LWFhNGQtNTFiZTE3ZjllZmUzNjU5MGNmNjktNjg3Yy00YmZlLWEwYWYtYmMzM2QxZmZlNjBk",
   "Raw": {
       "client_id": "demo",
       "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
       "response_type": "code id_token",
       "scope": "openid profile default-api",
       "response_mode": "form_post",
       "nonce": "636702233595840569.NGQ3NGVlODMtYTVhNy00MjM4LWFhNGQtNTFiZTE3ZjllZmUzNjU5MGNmNjktNjg3Yy00YmZlLWEwYWYtYmMzM2QxZmZlNjBk",
       "state": "CfDJ8DU4Xalc7d9HttaFlZ-UaDhGsjeeEccTfNiNZFz3yYZI9MfXjrXo2TAzT9f6-F2VEdC7bWtcD7HRJgkqrh4t0oTAe_47IBfcm5Fsde9bVRorq-CHcL6_c15Vz1G5LJyEzqX6tyjhcZ2g3J2JjxD1PME1W7sq9YSddhQUJmxt4bVi70wdTtXXp0tH0SKyb0vLCs3eIjOln792nobaFOCM7r3VJ8BfXfpDm2pOOmBlR7zCCBxFCivwj7Zmy5Tu8Z09MvzOaLEkPBSL5i9GyxmGiB0P6osBPYEDyoRfgy2qDigH3QqLmLYjfE6NrgcgIGO9kgXuUT52XgALV_ZKjNbih-Y",
       "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
       "x-client-ver": "2.1.4.0",
       "accessToken": "4155a526-2bb1-4d88-ba3a-21cb3a91f266",
       "userId": "MQ=="
   }
   ```

   }
3. > Showing login: User is not authenticated

---

It is not clear for me what caused the authentication failure, any idea?

Comment: Post the exception from the log

Comment: @Tseng There's no exception! or at least not showing in the log

Comment: Are you sure? The IdSrv4 should log an error or exception with more information why the auth request failed

Comment: Perhaps a required claim is not mapped, and through routing the user ends up at the login page. Is the page where you want the user to go protected by a certain role of policy?

Comment: @Tseng No erro, pretty sure. Although I set the flag `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII` to true

Comment: @Perhaps No, no policy, it just logins the user. However, it is in a different site than the backend (SPA), and no cookie is used (just bearer token passed in headers)

Comment: Perhaps the Authorize attribute is not looking at the right scheme. Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: The issue is discussed here https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1885

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. @Homam. have you resolved this issue if yes, Can you please share what have you done

Answer (score 36):

**TL;DR**: default identityserver using http + chrome, doesn't work. Chrome enforces that cookies with `SameSite=none` have also `Secure` attribute, so you may have to either use HTTPS, or modify the cookie policy using [@blow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60748736/1927444). [Chromium blog](https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html)

A bit of context on Single Sign On and cookies,

A cookie is a piece of information that a server sends on a `response` and the browser sends back on every subsequent `request`.

When you login into identityserver, it sends back multiple cookies, one of them identifies your session. This cookie is being sent with the attribute `SameSite=none` this allows any application that you browse to make a request to your identityserver and include this cookie with it. This way, the call to `/connect/authorize` includes this cookie, and identityserver skips the login part. *Voilà SSO*.

**Are you using `Google Chrome`?**

Google Chrome recently introduced a change where all cookies issued with the attribute `SameSite=none` **must include the `Secure` attribute.**

Those two attributes mean:

- [SameSite](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/): Controls how the browser will behave when attaching the cookie to any request made to your site, based on the origin.

  - `SameSite=strict`: does not send the cookie on requests made from sites different from the origin. This helps to prevent [CSRF](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf) attacks.
  - `SameSite=lax`: similar to `strict` but cookies get sent when the user   knowingly starts the request, by clicking a link or sending a form. Not being sent on requests initiated by scripts.
  - `SameSite=none`: the cookies will get included no matter which origin they come from.
- [Secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_cookie): Indicates that the cookie has to be sent over HTTPS only.

IdentityServer issues those cookies with `SameSite=none`. This means that when you're serving IdentityServer without HTTPS on local, and using chrome as browser, it won't log you in, because after you POST to the server your user & password, the response will include the session cookie but your browser (chrome) will refuse it because they're not marked as `secure` but, marked as `SameSite=none`, [and this combination is not allowed](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site).

Comment: If you use http redirection for local development it cause this situation. Both client web and ID Server must be https. Try it.

Comment: Is it possible to change the SameSite cookie behaviour in IdentityServer? I would set SameSite=Lax or Strict.

Comment: Thank you, I successfully set SameSite to Lax by setting the [CookiesPolicyOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60748736/195176)

Comment: I spent hours on this issue! Reading the first sentence of this post fixed my issue! thanks you!!!

Answer (score 24):

The cause is explaned by [Pablo Recalde answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60704777/195176), the right solutions is to use HTTPS.

Anyway, you can change `SameSite` value by setting [`CookiesPolicyOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cookie-policy-middleware)

Setting it to `SameSiteMode.Lax` you can force to use `SameSite=Lax` at least.

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions { MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax });
```