# Identity server 4 post login redirect not working in chrome only

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

i use identity server 4 let call it "auth-server" run on .net core 3.1.
there is angular app request authentication after redirected to auth-server and provide credentials submiting the login it's not redirect back to client app.
the issue is only in chrome browser (firefox & edge works fine)
i can see the redirect request - [Request-Url](http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=takbull-clientapp-dev&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fauth-callback%2F&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20takbull%20takbull.api&state=d3010be061224e4c975c5109c6a3fd83&nonce=28e892d37fd54beba744b777bd4cfa8f)
but it just go back to login page
Client congig:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    return new List<Client>(){
            new Client() {
                             RequireConsent =false,
                             RequireClientSecret = false,
                             ClientId = "takbull-clientapp-dev",
                             ClientName = "Takbull Client",
                             AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ImplicitAndClientCredentials,
                             AllowedScopes = new List<string> 
                             {
                              IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                              IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                              IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                              "takbull",
                              "takbull.api" 
                             },
                             // where to redirect to after login
                             RedirectUris = new List<string>()
                             {
                                 "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback/",
                                 "http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html",
                             },
                             //TODO: Add Production URL
                             // where to redirect to after logout
                             PostLogoutRedirectUris =new List<string>() 
                             {
                                 "http://localhost:4200"
                             },
                             AllowedCorsOrigins = {"http://localhost:4200"},
                             AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                             AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
                             AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
                         },
        };
    }
```

Login Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string button)
{
    // check if we are in the context of an authorization request
    var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);

    // the user clicked the "cancel" button
    if (button != "login")
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            // if the user cancels, send a result back into IdentityServer as if they 
            // denied the consent (even if this client does not require consent).
            // this will send back an access denied OIDC error response to the client.
            await _interaction.GrantConsentAsync(context, ConsentResponse.Denied);

            // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
            if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))
            {
                // if the client is PKCE then we assume it's native, so this change in how to
                // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                return View("Redirect", new RedirectViewModel { RedirectUrl = model.ReturnUrl });
             }

             return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
         }
         else
         {
            // since we don't have a valid context, then we just go back to the home page
            return Redirect("~/");
         }
     }

     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         // validate username/password against in-memory store
         var ValidResp = await _users.ValidateCredentials(model.Username, model.Password);
         if (ValidResp.LogInStatus == LogInStatus.Success)
         {
             var user = _users.FindByUsername(model.Username);
             //await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.Username, user.SubjectId, user.Username));
             await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.Email, user.UserId.ToString(), user.Email));

             // only set explicit expiration here if user chooses "remember me". 
             // otherwise we rely upon expiration configured in cookie middleware.
             AuthenticationProperties props = null;
             if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
             {
                 props = new AuthenticationProperties
                 {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                 };
             };

             // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
             //await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username, props);
             // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
             await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.UserId.ToString(), user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName, props, _users.GetClaims(user).ToArray());

             if (context != null)
             {
                 if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))
                 {
                     // if the client is PKCE then we assume it's native, so this change in how to
                     // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                     return View("Redirect", new RedirectViewModel { RedirectUrl = model.ReturnUrl });
                 }

                 // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
                 return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
             }

             // request for a local page
             if (Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
             {
                 return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
             }
             else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
             {
                 return Redirect("~/");
             }
             else
             {
                 // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
                 throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
             }
         }

         await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(model.Username, ValidResp.ResponseDescription));
         ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ValidResp.ResponseDescription);
     }

     // something went wrong, show form with error
     var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model);
     return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: forget to mention it was working fine and no changes was made at login flow

Answer (score 16):

I had issues with chrome and edge recently but a few months ago was only chrome.
So for me with .Net Core 3 and IdentityServer4 version 3.1.2 started working by adding the following code to startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ...)
    {
            app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
            {
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax
            });
```

**Note**: Make sure that you add this policy to the beginning of the Configure method not end in the startup.cs otherwise is not working.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue with IdentityServer4 on .NET Core 2.2. Your problem might be connected with those breaking changes in new  browsers versions like Chrome or Firefox:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/compatibility/3.0-3.1#http-browser-samesite-changes-impact-authentication

For me the working solution was to turn off the *SameSite* configuration for cookies at all. Such possibility for .NET Core 2.2 is described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1

(if your solution is on .NET Core 3.1 then in code below, instead using  *(SameSiteMode)(-1)* you should use *SameSiteMode.Unspecified*)

FIX:
in *Startup.cs* file in *ConfigureServices* method, right after *IdentityServerBuilder* is created...

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {....});
```

...I've added the following configuration change:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureExternalCookie(options => {
   options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
      options.Cookie.SameSite = (SameSiteMode)(-1); //SameSiteMode.Unspecified in .NET Core 3.1
   });

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
   options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
      options.Cookie.SameSite = (SameSiteMode)(-1); //SameSiteMode.Unspecified in .NET Core 3.1
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You will get below console warring in Google Chrome and your Identity server failed to redirect to Client App for Chrome version 80.

A cookie associated with a resource at was set with SameSite=None but without Secure. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies marked SameSite=None if they are also marked Secure. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

To Fix this , you need to do changes mention in below link -

https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/

NOTE : For .Net Core 2.2 , set SameSite = (SameSiteMode)(-1) , For .Net Core 3.0 or above , set SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified

Also , for Chrome 80 version , add this extra condition -

```
 if (userAgent.Contains("Chrome/8"))
 {
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: The Chrome 80 extra condiction can be added to this code:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/512959d4324b0ebfe1ca643add11c9362483d4bf/src/IdentityServer4/host/Extensions/SameSiteHandlingExtensions.cs#L10

Here you call the extenstion method:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/host/Startup.cs#L113.

But if Chrome hits version 90 or more it won't work anymore!

Answer (score 2):

Setting OpenidConnectionOptions worked for me

```
CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause is explaned by [Pablo Recalde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912757/identity-server-is-keep-showing-showing-login-user-is-not-authenticated-in-c/60704777#60704777) answer, the right solutions is to use HTTPS.

Anyway, you can change SameSite value by setting CookiesPolicyOptions

Setting it to SameSiteMode.Lax you can force to use SameSite=Lax at least.

app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions { MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax });

Answer (score 0):

You should add this following code in the ConfigureServices scope in Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication("MyCookie")
                .AddCookie("MyCookie", options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
                });
```