# Blazor authentication working on Azure, but on IIS in a VPS

Tags: identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a website using Blazor webassembly (and I like it). However, I have a problem: when I deploy my website on azure, authentication and authorization seem to work seemlessly, when I deploy it to my own VPS, somehow claims don't seem to get through, or JWT token, I can't tell.

Does anyone have a similar experience (and if so, have they found a solution)?

Thanx very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution to this, it has indeed to do with the time difference.
I put this in my ConfigureServices method in my Startup

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
          .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
                options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
                options.Clients.First().AccessTokenLifetime = 86400;
                options.Clients.First().IdentityTokenLifetime = 86400;

            });
```