# Blazor WASM + IdentityServer4 + Custom User Store

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1, blazor-client-side

I am working on a project in Blazor WASM client / API back end with IdentityServer4 for authentication and Dapper for data access to a custom user store. Much of the code is stolen directly from the below article

https://markjohnson.io/articles/asp-net-core-identity-without-entity-framework/

I have implemented my own classes for User, Role, UserStore, RoleStore, and SignInManager and have registered them in the startup of IdentityServer4 Quickstart project as below:

```
services.AddIdentity<CustomUser, CustomRole>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddSignInManager<CustomSignInManager>();
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
})
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
.AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
.AddAspNetIdentity<CustomUser>(); //Added recently
```

Also, in Configure method

```
 app.UseIdentityServer();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

From the Quickstart of IdentityServer4 Account Controller for Login Post:

```
  var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, 
              model.Password, model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: true);
  if (result.Succeeded)
  {
      var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
      if (context != null)
      {
          if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))
              return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", model.ReturnUrl);
```

The above code correctly uses my SignInManager and I get a successful password check.  The _userManager.FindByNameAsync finds and populates the user correctly, but when it reaches the "return this.LoadingPage" part...  it never goes back to the Blazor Client application.  The ID4 Login page just refreshes.

I found another person who was having similar issues with not re-routing and found they added the following code right before the return to redirect to theirs.  I tried it and it WORKS!!

```
if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))
{
 Claim[] claims = new Claim[] { new Claim("test", "test") };
 await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id.ToString(), user.UserName, claims);
 return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", model.ReturnUrl);
}
```

My question is...  Why is the HttpContext.SignInAsync required when I have my custom SignInManager and NOT when I use the default implementation?  Where SHOULD this code go?

Comment: Are you using chrome and serving identity server on local without TLS?

Comment: I don't see how browser would affect the ReturnURL string and handling, but yes, I'm using Chrome and it is running on localhost for now

Comment: Because I think that chrome is rejecting your cookies, so even your backend code works, if chrome doesn't save the cookie and sent it with every subsequent request, you're not logged. That's why you see the login page again. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912757/identity-server-is-keep-showing-showing-login-user-is-not-authenticated-in-c/60704777#60704777 but this is just a guess

Comment: ok.  I just checked, everything is running on HTTPS, so that would make it seem, according to how I read the linked article, as though it should work regardless of browser.  That being said, I tried the same test in Edge and it still does not work as expected. 

Additionally, I have a DIFFERENT project which does NOT have the custom user store which works fine.  So, I will reiterate my assertion that this is a code / setup related issue. 

The one which works is based on  https://medium.com/@marcodesanctis2/securing-blazor-webassembly-with-identity-server-4-ee44aa1687ef

Comment: Ok, I found part of an answer, but still have a question. Editing initial question.