# Identity Server 4: Google external provider : Can't redirect to my React client frontend after I sign in

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using Google as external provider to login in my app. The base url of my IdentityServer is https://localhost:5001. When I login on IS everything works nice: [tap here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3EAU.png). But when I try to login in React app via , I can't redirect to my homepage at all. I debugged my external controller and return URL which comes to Redirect method is valid. When I login in my React app via native IS wihout external provider I redirect to my homepage without problems and everything works excellent. I'm really confused. Code of external login controller:

```
    [SecurityHeaders]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class ExternalController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interaction;
        private readonly IClientStore _clientStore;
        private readonly ILogger<ExternalController> _logger;
        private readonly IEventService _events;
        public ExternalController(
            IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction,
            IClientStore clientStore,
            IEventService events,
            ILogger<ExternalController> logger)
        {
            _interaction = interaction;
            _clientStore = clientStore;
            _logger = logger;
            _events = events;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Challenge(string scheme, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) returnUrl = "~/";

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) == false && _interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl) == false)
            {
                throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
            }

            var props = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(Callback)),
                Items =
                {
                    { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                    { "scheme", scheme },
                }
            };

            return Challenge(props, scheme);

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
        {
            var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

            if (result?.Succeeded != true)
            {
                throw new Exception("External authentication error");
            }

            var externalUser = result.Principal;

            if (externalUser == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("External authentication error");
            }

            var claims = externalUser.Claims.ToList();

            var userIdClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            if (userIdClaim == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unknown userid");
            }

            var email = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimsTypes.Email).Value;
            var username = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimsTypes.Name).Value;
            var externalProvider = userIdClaim.Issuer;

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(new IdentityServerUser(userIdClaim.Value)
            {
                DisplayName = username,
                IdentityProvider = externalProvider,
                AdditionalClaims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email),
                },
                AuthenticationTime = DateTime.UtcNow
            });

            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);


            var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"] ?? "~/";

            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
    }
```

Client configuration ( my react app base url is http://localhost:3000 ):

```
  new Client()
                {
                    ClientId = "react-client-id",
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    ClientName = "React Client",
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = {"http://localhost:3000"},
                    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:3000/callback", "http://localhost:3000/refresh" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:3000/logout" },
                    AllowedGrantTypes =  GrantTypes.Code,
                    AllowedScopes = {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "PetAPI",
                        "ScheduleAPI"
                    }
                }
            };
```

OAuth config:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie()
    .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    });
```

Comment: When you log in via react, It can't redirect the HomePage? Does this only happen with react?

Comment: @XinranShen The problem is not in react, I guess. It's in my identity server itself. Yeah, when I login I can't redirect to home page. I even see return uri in my browser, but stuck on IdentityServer login page.

Comment: Is the return uri http instead of https? if so, the cookie might be getting rejected, meaning your session is not being picked up by your browser. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60704777/1927444 I think while your problem might be sightly different, it might be related. Look at your network panel, on the reply to the login POST see if there's a Warning sign near the Set-Cookie response header.